# Existence of analytic function on a unit dsic (Converse of Schwaraz Pick Lemma )

Tags: complex-analysis

(Schwarz - Pick Lemma) Suppose that $f$ is analytic on the Unit Disk $\triangle$ and satisfies the following two conditions :

(1) $|f(z) \leq 1$ for all z $\in \triangle$

(2) $f (a) = b $ for some $a , b \in \triangle$

Then

$$ |f'(a) | \leq \frac{1 - |f(a)|^2}{1 - |a|^2}$$

My question is.

$\bullet$  Is the converse of the Schwarz - Pick Lemma exist.

$\bullet$ Show that there exist an analytic function $ f : \triangle \rightarrow \triangle$ such that $f(1/2) = 0$ and $|f' (1/2)| \leq 4/3$ which satisfies the
$$ |f'(a) | \leq \frac{1 - |f(a)|^2}{1 - |a|^2}$$

Comment: what is a in this case?

Comment: @ M.L Nguyen $ a = 1/2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct me if I misunderstand your question. But here it is: It seems like if you require $a$ to be $1/2$, then the condition on the estimate of $|f'(a)|$ is redundant with the condition $|f'(1/2)|\leq 4/3$. Also, just from the fact that if such an analytic function $f$ satisfying $f(1/2)=0$ exists, it is totally possible for us to derive an estimate for $f'(1/2)$. To see this, consider the map $\phi:$ $z\mapsto \frac{z+1/2}{1+z/2} \in \text{Aut}(\mathbb{D})$. Then the composition $$g:=f\circ\phi: \mathbb{D} \longrightarrow \mathbb {D}$$ is a holomorphic map that fixes $0$. So by Schwarz' lemma and chain rule, we have: $$|\phi'(0)||f'(\phi(0))|=|g'(0)|\leq 1.(*)$$ Note that $\phi(0)=1/2$. Hence, $|f'(1/2)|\leq 4/3$.

Now the question is, does such function $f$ exist? Sure, I will give two examples:

- $f'(1/2)=4/3$ when the equality of $(*)$ takes place. That is when $g(z)=e^{i\theta}z$, from some $\theta$. Then $f=g\circ\phi^{-1}$, which means $f(z)=e^{i\theta}\frac{z-1/2}{1-z/2}$.
- If you want strict inequality, just take any analytic function on the unit disk that isn't an automorphism, and takes $1/2$ to $0$. For example, $z\mapsto 2z/3-1/3$ would certainly do the job.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is $\theta$ is fixed  here and Converse of Schwaraz pick lemma is hold and thanks for reply.

Comment: Yea. The angle should be fixed.

Comment: you have to used Schwaraz Lemma on $g(z)$ which says that equality hold  either $|f(z)|=|z|^n$ for some non zero $z \in \triangle$ or $|f^{(n)}(0)|=n \shortmid.$ iff $ f(z) = \epsilon z^n$, I think you have used Schwaraz Lemma on the basis of $|g(0)|=0$. Please check it